# Sleep command during startup, linux

Tags: linux, terminal, sleep, desktop, startup

I was wondering why this doesn't work and What I can do as an alternative. "sleep 10&&tilda" works in a regular console but doesn't seem to run during the startup cycle. I need to use the sleep because if I don't the tilda window doesn't look like it should.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are entering as a “command” here isn't a full shell prompt—you can only specify a command name and some arguments.  If you want to use a shell, you have to invoke it explicitly:

```
bash -c "sleep 10 && tilda"
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you for the help. I can't upvote you because I have no rep. ah well :)